# Is it possible to modify the labels on getUserMedia permission popup request?

Tags: javascript, cordova, web, web-applications, getusermedia

I’m developing a web app for android and iOS systems. On iOS every time I try to open the camera it asks for permission with this popup

[image]

Is it possible to use custom labels?

I’m using

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

to access the camera.

Thank you.

Comment: That could be a privacy breach ("Do you allow to block camera"?)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use custom labels in media permission popups?

No. For the sake of user privacy, the browsers insist on showing the web site that wants to use the user's media-capture device or devices.